# footnote reset in every page

Tags: numbering, footnotes

When using `\footnote{text}` in TeXnicCenter LaTeX, the number is reset in every new page. e.g:

- page one footnote 1,2,3
- page two footnote 1
- page three footnote 1,2,3
- ...

I want that the number associated with the footnote increment automatically in every chapter.

Comment: In light of the answer below, and due to the fact that you would like a fast solution, I recommend that you include a minimal example showing the problem you are having (to create a new page you can issue a command \newpage).

Comment: I forgot to say: Welcome to TeX and Friends! I hope you enjoy your stay!!

Comment: I removed the unnecessary stuff from the question. Could you please add more of the necessary stuff (as Yossi and lockstep suggested).

Answer (score 18):

By default, LaTeX does *not* reset the footnote number on every page (see example below). Could it be that your preamble includes `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}` or `\usepackage{footnpag}`?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{blindtext}

% \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{first}

\blindtext[2]\footnote{bla}

\blindtext[2]\footnote{blubb}

\blindtext[2]\footnote{foo}

\chapter{second}

\blindtext[2]\footnote{bar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find a solution with help of `chngcntr` package.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{footnote}{page}

\begin{document}
Make a footnote\footnote{1st}
\newpage
Make a footnote\footnote{2nd}
Make a footnote\footnote{3rd}
\newpage
Make a footnote\footnote{4th}
Make a footnote\footnote{5th}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work in full generality, because of the asynchronous page breaking mechanism.

Comment: Besides this being the opposite of what the OP wanted a better solution would be to use the [`perpage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/perpage) package and say `\MakePerPage{footnote}`